# wordpress database size widget

Tags: database, wordpress, widget

I have created a Wordpress widget, so far showing web files storage size.

I Would like to add Database size, so they know how big the database is within Wordpress admin panel.

I've asked on stack exchange, but no luck. Any help? Thanks
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289829/database-size-widget

Comment: "I've asked on StackExchange" - don't ask duplicate questions. Link your old question.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289829/database-size-widget

Answer (score 0):

This should work (executed as a query against the database):

```
SELECT  SUM(ROUND(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024 ), 2)) AS "SIZE 
IN MB"
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "<DATABASE_NAME>";
```

Comment: I got this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'SUM' (T_STRING) in /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/serv.php on line 110

Comment: Can you provide the exact SQL query? SUM isn't an unexpected word to be  after SELECT so I'm guessing there is something wrong with the format, maybe your quotes are wrong or you have it over multiple lines and that is causing the issue somehow?